# Geometric presentation of fundamental group of a surface

Tags: algebraic-topology, surfaces, fundamental-groups, low-dimensional-topology

Let $S = S_g$ be a closed surface.

An author of a paper writes:

> We say $\langle a_1, b_1, \cdots, a_{2g}, b_{2g} \ | \ R \rangle$ is a *geometric presentation* of the fundamental group $\pi_1(S)$ if the corresponding one vertex 2-complex is homeomorphic to S

Could somebody clarify exactly what this means?

I am familiar with the canonical presentation of $\pi_1(S)$, 
$$\pi_1(S) = \langle a_1, b_1, \cdots, a_{2g}, b_{2g} \ | [a_1,b_1] \cdots [a_{2g}, b_{2g}] = 1 \rangle  $$
and how it stems from idenitifying the sides of a hyperbolic 4g-gon, which labelled so that they spell out the product of the commutators $[a_1,b_1] \cdots [a_{2g}, b_{2g}]$, however I'm not sure how that translates to the definition above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of [Cayley complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_complex) helps.

Briefly, given a presentation $\langle x_1,...,x_n|R_1,...,R_k\rangle $ of a group, you construct a 2-dim complex as folows:

i) take a single vertex $v$

ii) attach to $v$ a loop $\gamma_i$ for any generator $x_i$

iii) for any relation of the form $x_{i_1}\cdots x_{i_s}=1$ attach a polygon with $s$ egdes the complex, by labeling edges $e_1,...,e_s$ and attaching $e_r$ to $x_{i_r}$

The result is the Cayley complex. Now, given $S$ and a presentation of $\pi_1(S)$ you wonder if the Cayley complex is homeomorphic to $S$ or not.

If yes, the author of the paper you are reading call such a presentation geometric.

An example of a non-geometric presentation could be constructed for instance by artificially adding generators and relations that kills them.

Answer (score 0):

The $4g$-gon with side identifications that you mention is exactly a one-vertex $2$-complex which is homeomorphic to $S$. So set $R = [a_1,b_1]\cdots [a_{2g},b_{2g}]$ and you're done.

Comment: Hi Dan, thank you for your answer. What I really want to know is what other relations are allowed? Also, what would make a presentation of $\pi_1(S)$ non-geometric?

Comment: Ah sorry, your question wasn't too clear on that point. The other user's answer involving the Cayley complex is probably what you're looking for.